How to add new multilingual post (WPML) with ACF frontend form?
WPML is used throughout the site for multilingualism.
A new multilingual post (2 languages, de/en) is to be created in a ACF frontend form.
A new post in one language can easily be created with ACF (ACF pro) frontend form.
However, the new post should always be created in both languages (from the frontend) at the same time.
How can I achieve this?

You can also give a try by adding the given code to the functions.php file of the theme.
Here we are using acf/save_post hook for inserting posts.
<?php
function custom_acfform_save_post( $post_id ) {
    // Check if this is the ACF form submission
    // here field_32146789bca is the field id.
    if ( isset( $_POST['acf']['field_32146789bca'] ) ) {
        
        $post_data = get_post( $post_id );
        
        // Here we are creating a new post array for the Primary post.
        $new_post = array(
            'post_title'  => $post_data->post_title,
            'post_content'=> $post_data->post_content,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type'   => 'post'
        );

        // Here we are inserting the new post in German Language.
        $new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post );

        if ( ! is_wp_error( $new_post_id ) ) {
            // Here we are setting up the post language to German using WPML.
            do_action('wpml_set_element_language_details', array(
                'element_id'    => $new_post_id,
                'element_type'  => 'post_post',
                'trid'          => apply_filters('wpml_element_trid', null, $post_id, 'post_post'),
                'language_code' => 'de',
                'source_language_code' => 'en'
            ));

            // Link the two posts together
            global $sitepress;
            $sitepress->set_element_translations(
                array(
                'post_post' => array(
                    'en' => $post_id,
                    'de' => $new_post_id
                    )
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'custom_acfform_save_post', 20);


Thanks for this interesting approach!
I got
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method SitePress::set_element_translation()

Could you please remove the given code and check once.
// Link the two posts together             global $sitepress;             $sitepress->set_element_translations(                 array(                 'post_post' => array(                     'en' => $post_id,                     'de' => $new_post_id                     )                 )             );

Thanks for help!
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method SitePress::set_element_translations()
Call to unknown method: SitePress::set_element_translations()
Avaiable methods are: set_element_language_details
and
set_element_language_details_action

We can use https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_set_element_language_details/

Since we are already using set_element_language_details hook in our code so we just need to remove the code mentioned below.
// Link the two posts together              global $sitepress;              $sitepress->set_element_translations(    array(                  'post_post' => array(                      'en' => $post_id,                      'de' => $new_post_id                      )                  )              );

I did already, trying out your code with in my setting.
Will come back soon.

Sure, I will be happy to help you out.

Was able to create 2 posts.
2nd post has only title of page with ACF Form, not the contents from ACF form, and has default language code, not the desired.
Default language code is de, desired en. Both are activated in WPML.

Could you please share the URL so I can check this, also more details can be found on https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_set_element_language_details/ regarding the implementation of what you are looking for.

Site is not yet deployed.
Thanks for the tip with the WPML API!

Can you please provide the screenshot of the same.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

What informations exactly do you need?

Thanks Narendra Sishodiya for pointing out the wpml-hooks (https://wpml.org/documentation/support/wpml-coding-api/wpml-hooks-reference/) and providing a first working script.
This hook does the job:
wpml_copy_post_to_language.

To add a new multilingual post using WPML on the frontend, first, create your post in the default language. Then, switch to the desired language using the WPML language switcher. Finally, translate the content and publish the post. This is the easiest way I found.

Thanks. But this kind of multilingual post on this site should be created in a ACF frontend form.

We can create a new multilingual post in both languages (German and English) from an ACF frontend form, we need to integrate WPML functionality with our ACF form submissions.
We need to Create Custom ACF Frontend Form. Use acf/save_post hook which allows you to run custom functions after an ACF form saves the post. We can use WPML's API to create the translated post in the secondary language. We need to duplicate content from the primary language and then set the language of the new post using WPML's functions.
